# why can't I Drag&Drop on a disabled grid?

Tags: grid, extjs4

I have 2 grid, one that's disabled initially. 
There's a drag/drop configured between the 2 grids. I would think that drag&drop won't work on the grid that's disabled, but apparently it does.

Any idea how to prevent it? Is this a bug?

Comment: Well I had said that this is normal behavior cause you may check the drop-target along with the `beforedrop` event. But on a quick test I couldn't find the drop target, only the drop source... So yes, this is a bit curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent this by disabeling your D&D plugin on disable of your grid. And enable it back when your grid is enabled (or whenever you want).

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. I guess it is a bug. But the first record can be dropped and again removed. After that it is disabled. Tested with ExtJS 4.1.3

Comment: It does work, you can disable the plugin and you won't be able to drop the record, if you enable your plugin again then it will be posible again. I'm using 4.1.1 though, I don't have a support account ;-).

Doesn't change the fact that it is a bug, and the plugin should be disabled on disable of the grid.

Comment: Well, The first sentence is a bit misleading I guess :) But with 4.1.3 it is indeed buggy. So this Version should be skipped and the next one checked.

Comment: This does indeed work. I manually enable/disable the plugin of the grid. Still too much work for something that seems like default behavior to me, but at least it's working.